# Can ping myself but nothing else

Tags: networking

I have a Linux server that was configured to be accessible via a TP-Link wr1024d router. I configured the LAN side of the router, then reserved an IP address for the server. I edited the */etc/network/interfaces* file to reflect the ip address including the gateway, broadcast, and the dns-nameserver address.
I can only ping myself. I cannot ping the other devices on the same TP-Link Router, neither can I ping the gateway. I also cannot access the Internet. If I connect another computer to the same Router (using the same port), I can use the Internet.
Any help please? Thanks!

For the `ifconfig` command:

```
eth1  Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 94:57:
    inet address:197.210.* Bcast:197.210.* Mask:255.255.*
    inet6 addr::fe80:9657:*:*:/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
    RX packets:3581 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets: 10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txueuelen:1000
    RX bytes 1037762 (1013.4 KiB) TX bytes: 818 (818.0 B)
    Interrupt:18

lo  Link encap:Local lopback
    inet addr: 127.0.0.1 Mask: 255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
    RX packets: 10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets: 10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:840 (840.0 B) TX bytes:840 (840.0 B)_
```

For the contents of the `interfaces` file:

```
#The loopback network interface
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

#for the interface 
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 197.210.*
  netmask 255.255.*
  broadcast 197.210.*
  network 197.210.*
  gateway 197.210.*
  dns-nameservers 83.*
```

Finally, for the `netstat -rn` command:

```
 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination: 197.210.*
 Gateway: 0.0.0.0
 Genmask: 255.255.*
 Flags: U
 MSS:0
 Window:0
 irtt:0
 Iface:eth1
```

I do hope it's clear enough now.. real sorry for the other time!

Comment: Please add the output of `ifconfig` and the contents of your `interfaces` file to the question.

Comment: And your routing table: `netstat -rn`

Comment: Please edit your question with this information. This ugly formatted comment is making it unreadable. And there is not output of `netstat -r` command.

Comment: I've done that.
Thanks for your timely response @jos

Comment: Did you restart the network? `sudo systemctl restart networking` (or `sudo service networking restart` on older systems).

Comment: Can you confirm from other devices on the same network that the gateway (router) IP address is indeed x.169?

Comment: It's now working. I think the reboot + a couple of port forwarding did it.
Thank you!!! @Jos and fugitive